# my logcat displays stuff continuosly

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

i tried to implement gcm client in android and display the registration id on logcat.but the logcat is continuosly display some stuff other than what i intend to display.

```
package in.myreceiver.gcm;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;

public class SeriousBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
try{
    String action=intent.getAction();
    if(action.equals("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION"))
    {
        String registrationId=intent.getStringExtra("registration_Id");
        Log.i("uo",registrationId);
        String error=intent.getStringExtra("error");
        String unregistered=intent.getStringExtra("unregistered");          
    }

    else if(action.equals("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE"))
    {
        String data1=intent.getStringExtra("data1");
        String data2=intent.getStringExtra("data2");

    }
}
finally{}
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Search for your tag "uo"... LogCat is showing all Logs from the device (OS and so on)

Comment: but its stopping printing the stuff...it jst goes on n on

Comment: As long as you connected your device over USB logcat will output any logs from the device ;) This is normal

Comment: ok...but something is wrong in my code only...cz there are a lot of runtime errors

Comment: btw...m very new to android programming...i havnt programmed in android much. n i need to implement a push-notification...so can you please tell what all i need to learn and where to look for it?

Comment: Well the site androidhive.Info or vogella.com ;) helped me a lot